# How can I interpret a relationship of two entities into a table?

Tags: sql, database, entities, relationships, database-table

I have these two tables called the "article" and the "head editor". So the relationship is represented as "the article is passed to the editor" and the relationship has an attribute called "datesubmitted".

I was wondering how I can make the relationship of the two entities into a table?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to try something on your own, before posting questions. Also, there are heaps of tutorials which will show exactly what you are asking.
Just give a try with 'SQL JOIN' on google

Answer (score 0):

If an article has only one head editor, it's a 1:n relationship.
1 head editor can be head editor of n articles but 1 article can only have 1 head editor, so you can add a foreign key (HeadEditorId or something similar) to your article table.

If an article can have more then 1 head editor, you should use a third table in which you have foreign keys of the article and the head editor because it would represent a n:n relationship.

If you want to query over the two tables, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Article AS a
INNER JOIN HeadEditor AS he
    ON a.HeadEditorId = he.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Article
    ----------
    ID
    HeadEditorID

    HeadEditor
    -----------
    ID
    DateSubmitted
```